# window.location.href need to remove hostname

Tags: php, html

I am using the following syntax

```
url:'<?php echo $marker[url];?>

window.location.href=this.url;
```

on click I am redirected to address:  localhost/www.xyz.com

while I need it to redirect to only www.xyz.com without localhost name.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What does `this` refer to?

Comment: Your question is not clear, please describe more

Comment: make sure your url starts with either `http://` or `https://` - otherwhise it will see it as internal link.

Comment: make url start with // or http:// using concat (.) or + to concat texts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this error may caused by your method to encodeUrl. Check your url, just encode parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If a URL begins with a hostname, you need to put the `//` prefix before it, to indicate that there's a hostname there. Otherwise, it's treated as a filename relative to the location of the current page. So it should be:

```
window.location.href = '//' + this.url;
```

Comment: I tried your method, now I am getting     http://localhost//www.znapster.com while I need output as www.znappster.com

Comment: solved. yes now its working. I used your rule to add '//' +   Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user2885237 Why did you accept a different answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough to give an exact answer.

You can try using "http://" or "//" followed by the URL. 
Without using http:// or "//" it may redirect to localhost/www.xyz.com

Comment: Thanks, in my output localhost name is getting added to URL which I dont want. on click it should only direct to exact www.xyz.com

Answer (score 0):

Answer is: '//' + this.url thanks to all replies to this thread.

Comment: @Barmar already provided answer. You should accept it instead of stating that you find the answer.